# Can I change this three loops into one or do something else to make this code faster?

Tags: python, performance, loops, velocity

I need help with this code in python 'cause this is too slow for me. I'd like to make this faster but I have no idea how. I think loops have to be less. I have even calculated that (length - 2) ^ 3 = length^3 + 12 * length - 6 * (length^2) - 8 but I don't have any concepts how to use it. Please help! Code :

```
word = "a word"
letter_1 = ""
letter_2 = ""
letters = list(word)
length = len(letters)
string = ""
number = 0
number2 = 0
words = []

for i in range(length - 2):
    letter_1 = letters[i]

    for j in range(i + 1,length - 1):
        
        if letters[j] != letter_1:
            letter_2 = letters[j]
            
            for k in range(j + 1, length):
                
                if letters[k] != letter_2:
                    string = letter_1 + letter_2 + letters[k]
                    number += 1
                    
                    if not string in words:
                        words.append(string)
                        number2 += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Help us help you: Please explain what your algorithm is  supposed to do so that we don't have to reverse-engineer it and can help you more easily. Just edit your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code tries to get all the unique trigrams in a string named `word`. If my assumption is not correct, please ignore my answer and correct me.

If it is the case though, I suggest the following to improve it:

1. Since you want unique results, a list is not ideal, use a set; replacing `words = []` by `words = set()` and `words.append(string)` by `words.add(string)`
2. Since you're doing a left-to-right check for unique trigrams when you find a letter in the first position when you encounter it again in the first position you may ignore it, as you are sure you already traversed all the combinations with such letter in the first position; so you can create additional sets to verify if a letter was already checked in a position:

   E.g. for `word =  'aabc'` you first get `a` in the first position, and check it against `a`, `b`, and `c`; when you get `a` again in the first position you don't need to check it against the following letters once more

   The same goes for the second position, so you can create a variable for prefixes already checked `seen_prefixes = set()`; and then:

   ```py
   word = "a word"
   letter_1 = ""
   letter_2 = ""
   letters = list(word)
   length = len(letters)
   string = ""
   number = 0
   number2 = 0
   words = set()
   seen_prefixes = set()

   for i in range(length - 2):
       letter_1 = letters[i]
       # check for prefix and add if is a new prefix
       if letter_1 in seen_prefixes:
           continue
       seen_prefixes.add(letter_1)

       for j in range(i + 1,length - 1):

           if letters[j] != letter_1:
               letter_2 = letters[j]
               # check for prefix and add if is a new prefix
               if letter_1 + letter_2 in seen_prefixes:
                   continue
               seen_prefixes.add(letter_1 + letter_2)

               for k in range(j + 1, length):

                   if letters[k] != letter_2:
                       string = letter_1 + letter_2 + letters[k]
                       number += 1

                       if not string in words:
                           words.add(string)
                           number2 += 1
   ```

   Bear in mind that if the value of variable `number` (I'm assuming is the number of checked trigrams) is important, this improvement will not suit you

These are improvements I suppose could work to improve the speed since the number of iterations will be significantly smaller, especially when your `word` variable gets bigger.

Not related to performance, but I'd also suggest making your code a bit more readable, perhaps encapsulating some loops and renaming variables e.g. `number` to `checked_trigrams` and `number2` to `unique_trigrams_found`

Comment: So I think that your answer is helpful 'cause I need to get my program more speed. So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special function for that in the package `itertools` called `combinations`

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations("a word", 3))
[('a', ' ', 'w'), ('a', ' ', 'o'), ('a', ' ', 'r'), ('a', ' ', 'd'), ('a', 'w', 'o'), ('a', 'w', 'r'), ('a', 'w', 'd'), ('a', 'o', 'r'), ('a', 'o', 'd'), ('a', 'r', 'd'), (' ', 'w', 'o'), (' ', 'w', 'r'), (' ', 'w', 'd'), (' ', 'o', 'r'), (' ', 'o', 'd'), (' ', 'r', 'd'), ('w', 'o', 'r'), ('w', 'o', 'd'), ('w', 'r', 'd'), ('o', 'r', 'd')]
```